# ĉioscia kaj ĉionscia(nta)

Tags: word-formation

Mi ne sukcesas trovi klarigon aŭ pravigon gramatikan por la adjektivo *ĉioscia*.

Mi uzas *ĉionscia*, sed [kaj PIV](https://vortaro.net/#%C4%89ioscia_kd) [kaj Tekstaro](https://tekstaro.com/?s=62d30ba5a753) listigas **nur** uzojn de *ĉioscia* (sen *-n*).

Tamen [Zamenhof uzis](https://tekstaro.com/?s=62d30c8b9d0e5) *ĉionscianta* (kun *-n*) kaj ankaŭ en Tekstaro oni trovas *ĉioscianta* (sen *-n*).

Mi povus kompreni la mankon de *-n* se la *-o* estus [interliga finaĵo](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/principoj/antauelementoj.html#i-pce), kiel en fruktodona (fruktdona ne facile eldireblas), sed ĉi okaze ne ŝajnas temi pri tio.

Ĉu estas gramatika klarigo por la manko de *-n* en la kunmetaĵo adektiva de *ĉio* kaj *scii*? Similajn kunmetaĵojn oni trovas en Tekstaro, kaj kun *-n* kaj sen ĝi, kvazaŭ ne estus regulo en la lingvo, kaj ambaŭ validus: *ĉiopova*, *ĉioscia*, *ĉiovida*, *ĉio**n**penetra*, *ĉio**n**detrua*, *ĉio**n**vidanta* ...

Comment: And then there is also the two words alternative; _ĉion vidanta_ - for instance when spoken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PMEG donas du klarigojn.

Sube de tiu subĉapitro pri interligaj finaĵoj estas subĉapitro pri [objekto kiel antaŭelemento](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/principoj/antauelementoj.html#i-8zu), en kiu oni konstatas, ke la antaŭelemento en *leterskribi* "ne estas ordinara objekto, sed montras karakterizaĵon de agospeco".

Miaopinie pli klara klarigo estas en la ĉapitro [37.4 Vortigo de frazetoj](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/principoj/frazetvortigo.html). En tiu ĉapitro PMEG priskribas, kiel oni konstruas kunmetaĵojn de frazetoj aŭ kunapartenantaj vortoj. Oni retenas nur la plej gravajn elementojn de la frazeto, sed ne ekzemple j- kaj n-finaĵojn.

Ni ja havas ekzemplojn:

- skribi leteron → leterskribi
- doni voĉon → voĉdoni
- provi kapti fiŝojn → fiŝkapti
- akiri per laboro → perlabori

Kompreneble oni povas krei derivaĵojn de tiuj vortoj.

- Ĉu vi ne havas tamen ian suspekton pri la leterskribanto?
- Voĉdono estas maniero kolektive decidi pri io.
- Ni invitas ĉiujn al fiŝkaptado.
- perlaborita enspezo

Laŭ tiu modelo:

- scii ĉion → ĉioscii → ĉioscianta

Comment: Dankon. Do, ĉu aldoni la `-n` estus malĝuste laŭ tiu klarigo?

Comment: Jes, ne havu -n en kunmetaĵoj.